# Split String but Return whole word at the end

Tags: c#

I am using the following function to split a string into chunks

```
public static IList<string> SplitChunks(string text, int chunkSize)
{
    List<string> chunks = new List<string>();
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < text.Length)
    {
        int size = Math.Min(chunkSize, text.Length - offset);
        chunks.Add(text.Substring(offset, size));
        offset += size;
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

Works fine but the issue is in many cases the chunk ends with an incomplete word such as

**Input:**

> String: Hello Everyone. How are you?
>
> Size: 10

**Output:**

> Hello Ever

where I want it to return a full last word such as `Hello Everyone`

How can I modify my function so the last word is a full word regardless of the `size` of the chunk

Comment: consider using a regular expression.

Comment: split the string on spaces, build a table of lengths of each component, then it should be easy to see which word crosses the point of 10 characters (size),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string into words and then try to generate chunks of at least `chunkSize` size:

```
public static IList<string> SplitChunks(string text, int chunkSize)
{
    var words = text.Split(' ');
    var result = new List<string>();
    int length = 0;
    string current = "";
    foreach(var word in words)
    {
        current += word + " ";
        length += word.Length + 1;

        if (length > chunkSize) {
            result.Add(current);
            current = "";
            length = 0;
        }
    }
    if (current != "")
        result.Add(current);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , Splitting words works perfectly and fits right into what I wanted to do. Highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, but it's a bit ugly because it's producing a side effect in the `TakeWhile`:

```
int count = 0;
const string text = "Hello Everyone. How are you?";
var ret = text.TakeWhile(s =>
{
    var keepTaking = count < max;
    count += s.Length + 1; // +1 for the space between words
    return keepTaking;
});
```

Comment: and what's `words` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too:

```
public static IList<string> SplitChunks(string text, int chunkSize)
{
    var parts = text.Split(' ');
    return parts.Skip(1).Aggregate(parts.Take(1).ToList(), (a, x) =>
    {
        if ((a.Last() + x).Length > chunkSize)
            a.Add(x);
        else
            a[a.Count - 1] += " " + x;
        return a;
    });
}
```

When I call `SplitChunks("Hello Everyone. How are you?", 10)` I get this:

```
Hello 
Everyone. 
How are 
you?
```

Comment: Thank you, definitely give it a try